# php if statement with multiple operators (or, and)

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, compare

I'd like to compare different values before executing a specific function. Including local time, which I get like this:

```
$localTime = new DateTime('@' . $localTimestamp);
$localTime = [
    0 => $localTime->format('H'),
    1 => $localTime->format('i')
];

// print_r($localTime) looks like this:
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 25
)
```

Here is the if statement:

```
if ((($localTime[0] === 10) || ($localTime[0] === 11 && $localTime[1] >= 0 && $localTime[1] < 30)) && $localTimestamp - strtotime($latestSession) < 900) { // 15 minutes
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function  () on line X (line with if statement).

Comment: Works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/erv8c. You do need to change your `===` to `==` as `$localTime` is an array of strings, not integers.

Comment: @Nick I use the use the pre installed php service on Mac. Can this cause some problem?

Comment: @Nick version 7.1.23

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the Mac PHP service. Note though that your code did need an edit (I edited my previous comment) but it certainly doesn't get an defined function error.

Comment: @Nick hmm, it doesn work

Comment: Missing `()` in the last statement? You doing `-` operator and then compare the result with `<` - try surrounding it with brackets

Comment: Can you update you question with what are you trying to achieve? It seems to be possibly optimized and made more readable.

Comment: @freeek basic operations like this if ($localTime[0] == 10 || ($localTime[0] == 11) doesn't work at all.

Comment: Just express your wish in plain English: "If time is between ten or eleven o'clock or ..." and etc.

Comment: You can also publish your sample code. that produces such error somewhere like [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Comment: @freeek solved :) --> ($localTime[0] == 10 || $localTime[0] == 11 && $localTime[1] >= 0 && $localTime[1] <= 30 || $localTime[0] >= 14 && $localTime[0] <= 4) {

Comment: You are welcome to post an answer by yourself with some comments then.